# Reducing the line of collision of two rigidbodies while using the coefficient of restitution

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, collision, rigid-body-dynamics

I am trying to solve the problem of the collision of any two rigid-bodies. So far this is what I got:
[image: Image of current state of solution]

I am concerned with the part where I reduce the equation with the coefficient of restitution by $\vec{n}$. As far as I know it can be factored out and the fraction, reduced. Yet, I am unsure as it seems to me, that it would make the line of collision redundant, while it is critical, as the COR is defined only on it.

Can I reduce the fraction by $\vec{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you understand that you cannot divide two vectors. Instead the COR is used in the following scalar equation describing the law of collisions.

$$ \boldsymbol{n} \cdot (\boldsymbol{v}_{1c}^\text{after} - \boldsymbol{v}_{2c}^\text{after} ) = - \epsilon \, \boldsymbol{n} \cdot ( \boldsymbol{v}_{1c}^\text{before} - \boldsymbol{v}_{2c}^\text{before}) \tag{1}$$

where the vector $\boldsymbol{n}$ is the contact normal, and $\cdot$ is the vector dot product. Also $\boldsymbol{v}_{1c}$ denotes body *1* velocity vector at the contact point, etc.

This equation is used to find the impulse magnitude $J$ for the collision. Each body has equal and opposite impulse vector $\boldsymbol{n} J$ applied, creating a step (change) in the velocity and rotation in each body.

Here $\boldsymbol{r}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{r}_2$ is the COM positions of each body, and $\boldsymbol{r}_c$ the contact point.

So the impulse vector through the contact point has the following effect in the motion of each body

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \Delta \boldsymbol{v}_1 & = -\tfrac{1}{m_1} \boldsymbol{n} J & \Delta \boldsymbol{v}_2 & = \tfrac{1}{m_2} \boldsymbol{n} J \\ 
  \Delta \boldsymbol{\omega}_1 &= -\mathbf{I}_1^{-1} ( \boldsymbol{r}_c-\boldsymbol{r}_1) \times \boldsymbol{n} J & \Delta \boldsymbol{\omega}_2 &= \mathbf{I}_2^{-1} ( \boldsymbol{r}_c-\boldsymbol{r}_2) \times \boldsymbol{n} J
\end{aligned} \tag{2} $$

where $\Delta \boldsymbol{v}_i$ is the vector change of body's center of mass, and $\Delta \boldsymbol{\omega}_i$ the vector change of the body's rotational velocity.

And the kinematics of the contact point before impact are

$$ \begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{v}_{1c}^\text{before} & = \boldsymbol{v}_1 + \boldsymbol{\omega}_1 \times (\boldsymbol{r}_c - \boldsymbol{r}_1) \\ \boldsymbol{v}_{2c}^\text{before} & = \boldsymbol{v}_2 + \boldsymbol{\omega}_2 \times (\boldsymbol{r}_c - \boldsymbol{r}_2)  \\
\end{aligned} \tag{3} $$

and after impact

$$ \begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{v}_{1c}^\text{after} & = (\boldsymbol{v}_1+\Delta \boldsymbol{v}_1) + ( \boldsymbol{\omega}_1 +\Delta \boldsymbol{\omega}_1) \times (\boldsymbol{r}_c - \boldsymbol{r}_1) \\ \boldsymbol{v}_{2c}^\text{after} & = (\boldsymbol{v}_2+\Delta \boldsymbol{v}_2) +  (\boldsymbol{\omega}_2 + \Delta \boldsymbol{\omega}_2)\times (\boldsymbol{r}_c - \boldsymbol{r}_2)  \\
\end{aligned} \tag{4}$$

Now use (2) into (4), and then user (3) & (4) into (1) to get one equation in terms of $J$.

First find the impact speed $v_{\rm impact} = \boldsymbol{n} \cdot ( \boldsymbol{v}_{1c}^\text{before} - \boldsymbol{v}_{2c}^\text{before}) $ which is a known quantity.

Then form the law of collisions

$$\boldsymbol{n}\cdot\left(\Delta\boldsymbol{v}_{1}+\Delta\boldsymbol{\omega}_{1}\times(\boldsymbol{r}_{c}-\boldsymbol{r}_{1})-\Delta\boldsymbol{v}_{2}-\Delta\boldsymbol{\omega}_{2}\times(\boldsymbol{r}_{c}-\boldsymbol{r}_{2})\right)=-\left(1+\epsilon\right)\,v_{{\rm impact}} \tag{5}$$

and factor out $J$ in preparation for solving.

$$ \begin{split}\Bigl\{\tfrac{1}{m_{1}}+\tfrac{1}{m_{2}}-\boldsymbol{n}\cdot(\boldsymbol{r}_{c}-\boldsymbol{r}_{1})\times\mathbf{I}_{1}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{r}_{c}-\boldsymbol{r}_{1})\times\boldsymbol{n}\\
-\boldsymbol{n}\cdot(\boldsymbol{r}_{c}-\boldsymbol{r}_{2})\times\mathbf{I}_{2}^{-1}(\boldsymbol{r}_{c}-\boldsymbol{r}_{2})\times\boldsymbol{n}\Bigr\} J & =\left(1+\epsilon\right)\,v_{{\rm impact}}
\end{split}
 \tag{6} $$

I like the think of the solution as $  J = (1+\epsilon) m_{\rm reduced} v_{\rm impact} $ where I factor all the mass/inertia terms into a reduced mass for the contact.

Once $J$ is known, then use (2) to find the change of motion for both bodies.

References:

- [An Introduction to Physically Based Modeling, Part 2](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebaraff/sigcourse/notesd2.pdf)